# Too much recursion when attempting to serialize object

Tags: c#, recursion, serialization, yaml

I'm currently testing usage of YML in my application, to provide a more friendly means to editing and configuring e-mail downloads and imports for users.

For testing purposes, I wanted to see if my mocked-up YML is roughly equivalent to what the application would put out.

So, for testing I have this block of code, and it never fails to throw "Too much recursion".

```
// TEST SERIALIZE DATA
        {
            var _testDomain = default(Domain);
            var _testSecureString = new SecureString();

            "testP455w0rd".ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(_testSecureString.AppendChar);

            var _testConfig = new EmailBeamConfig() {
                DefaultProtocol = ProtocolType.Imap,
                Domains = new List<Domain> {
                    (_testDomain = new Domain {
                        Accounts = new List<EmailAccount> {
                            new EmailAccount {
                                Domain = _testDomain.DomainName,
                                InternalUid = "de.test_a_test-account",
                                Password = _testSecureString,
                                Username = "test-account@test.de"
                            },
                            new EmailAccount {
                                Domain = _testDomain.DomainName,
                                InternalUid = "de.test_a_test-account2",
                                Password = _testSecureString,
                                Username = "test-account2@test.de"
                            }
                        },
                        DomainName = "de.test",
                        EmailServer = "192.168.252.172",
                        UseEncryption = true
                    })
                },
                DownloadInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                DownloadRoot = mainSystemConfig.GetString("importRootDir")
            };

            var _testSerializer = new SerializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(new UnderscoredNamingConvention())
                .Build();
            var _testSerializedData = _testSerializer.Serialize(_testConfig);

            File.WriteAllText(cfgFile.FullName, _testSerializedData);
        }
```

Here is the source to EmailBeamConfig:

```
internal class EmailBeamConfig {

    private string _downloadRoot;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the download root dir.
    /// </summary>
    public string DownloadRoot {
        get => _downloadRoot;
        set {
            _downloadRoot = value;
            DownloadRootObj = new DirectoryInfo(value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an object representing the download root.
    /// </summary>
    public DirectoryInfo DownloadRootObj { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the interval for downloading e-mails.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan DownloadInterval { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the default protocol to be used,
    /// if a protocol is not defined for an individual user.
    /// </summary>
    public ProtocolType DefaultProtocol { get; set; }

    public List<Domain> Domains { get; set; }

}
```

And EmailAccount:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an e-mail account for use in this plugin.
/// </summary>
internal struct EmailAccount {

    private string _internalUid;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the username for this e-mail account.
    /// (Used for logging in, etc)
    /// </summary>
    internal string Username { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the password for this account.
    /// </summary>
    internal SecureString Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the internal user identifier for this user account.
    /// </summary>
    internal string InternalUid {
        get => _internalUid;
        set {
            if (value == "/" || value.Length < 10) {
                _internalUid = $"{ Domain }_a_{ Username?.Split('@')[0] }";
            } else _internalUid = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the domain this e-mail account is associated with.
    /// </summary>
    internal string Domain { get; set; }

}
```

I'm completely oblivious to any source of infinite recursion at this point.

**EDIT:** Here is the Domain struct declaration:

```
internal struct Domain {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of this domain.
    /// </summary>
    internal string DomainName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the URL/IP address of the e-mail server.
    /// </summary>
    internal string EmailServer { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value determining whether to attempt to use an encrypted connection to 
    /// the e-mail server.
    /// </summary>
    internal bool UseEncryption { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of accounts associated with this domain
    /// </summary>
    internal List<EmailAccount> Accounts { get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of the `Domain` class?

Comment: Domain is a struct, hang on, I'll add it to the OP

Comment: When it throws the error have you looked at the call stack? That may give you an idea of what is causing it to get stuck going round in circles.

Comment: The stack trace only shows me library-internal code. Nothing that really helps me :/